# Fatal Error while trying to use require_once in php

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, server

I am trying to connect my php script with my database in an online server. I am trying to use require_once function however, I am getting the fatal_error with the following error message.

```
Warning: require_once(/home/username/public_html/droidDBtest/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/username/public_html/droidDBtest/android_login_api/register.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/username/public_html/droidDBtest/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/username/public_html/droidDBtest/android_login_api/register.php on line 3
```

I tried to follow the first result's of stackoverflow and added Document Root, however, it's still not working. 
This is the code where I am getting an error :

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php');
```

The following is my folder structure in my server

```
 public_html/
     -- droidDBtest
        -- android_login_api
            -- include
                 config.php
                 DB_Connect.php
                 DB_Functions.php
               register.php
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see if you compare the error message with your folder structure, you're missing the `android_login_api` folder.

This should work:

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php');
```

Also, it appears you're doing this from `register.php` inside the `android_login_api` folder. So you can do this as a relative path:

```
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
```

Comment: I just updated my code but I am still getting the same error (Slightly modified)... I have updated my problem statement with current error.

Comment: @ibtehaz then carefully compare the error message (which includes the _full path_ that it is failing to find) to your actual directory structure, and it should be pretty simple to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Lookin at your directory structure, and assuming socument root is public_html, you shoud do this:

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/droidDBtest/android_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php');
```

Comment: I am getting two droidDBtest folder name

Comment: Check owner and file permissions. Output here ls -l command for that include file